# Validar registros Java si existe o No

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito saber cuál es la manera de que me valide si existe o no algún registro en una base de datos.

Este es el código de buscar (no hay error en sí):

```
public void buscar(String id_usu) {
        try {
            conectar conexion = new conectar();
            Connection con = conexion.getconectar();
            String sentencia = "SELECT * FROM evaluacion_antropometrica WHERE id_usu="+id_usu+" ";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sentencia);
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
                    row[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
               }
            }
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Identificacion: "+row[1]+"\nPeso :"+row[2]+"\nEstatura:"+row[3]+"\nmedida brazo izquierdo:"+row[4]+"\nmedida brazo derecho:"+row[5]+"\nmedida pecho:"+row[6]+"\nmedida pierna izquierda:"+row[7]+"\nmedida pierna derecha:"+row[8]+"\nmedida cintura:"+row[9]+"\npantorrilla izquierda:"+row[10]+"\npantorrilla derecha:"+row[11]+"\nimc resultado:"+row[12]+"\ncuello:"+row[13]+"\nimcverificar:"+row[14]+"\nMedida gluteos:"+row[15]+"\nMedida antebrazo izquierdo:"+row[16]+"\nMedida antebrazo derecho:"+row[17]);

         //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Estatura usuario: "+row[1]+"\nPeso usuario:"+row[2]+"\nmedida brazo izquierdo:"+row[3]+"\nmedida brazo derecho:"+row[4]+"\nmedida pecho:"+row[5]+"\nmedida pierna izquierda:"+row[6]+"\nmedida pierna derecha:"+row[7]+"\nmedida cintura:"+row[8]+"\npantorrilla izquierda:"+row[9]+"\npantorrilla derecha:"+row[10]+"\nimcresultado:"+row[11]+"\ncuello:"+row[12]+"\nimc verificar:"+row[13]+"\nIdentificacion:"+row[14]+"\nMedida gluteos:"+row[15]);
            conexion.desconectar();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // cierra buscar
```

Comment: Donde falla? Cual es el error?

Comment: necesito saber cual es la manera de que me valide si existe o no un registro en una base de datos no hay error en si porque ese es el codigo de buscar

Comment: Veo que solo usaste un parámetro, que sucedió con el otro?

Answer (score 5):

A nivel de rendimiento, hacer un `SELECT * ...` para verificar si un registro existe es una mala práctica.

Supongamos una tabla con 10, 20 ó 150 columnas... ¡estás seleccionado **todas las columnas** solamente para determinar si hay registros!

Yo crearía un método, el cual quizá formaría parte de mi clase `Connection` (la que use para conectarme a la base de datos), que reciba dos parámetros: una instrucción SQL y el valor a filtar. El mismo método se puede adaptar para que reciba instrucciones SQL con o sin datos a filtar, o para que filtre en base a varios criterios  en vez de uno solo, pasándole los parámetros en un array. De ese modo utilizarías ese método **cada vez que necesites verificar si un registro existe en la BD**.

Entonces, en la clase `Connection`... o como se llame, podrías crear un método como este:

```
public boolean ifExists(String sSQL, int nId) {
    PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
    ps.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    return rs.next();
}
```

Usamos el método `next()` de la  Clase [**`Resultset`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) el cual devolverá `false` si no encuentra registros o por el contrario devolverá `true`.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
If (db.ifExists ("Select 1 from nombteTabla where id = ?;")){
//Existe registro
}else{
//No hay registros
}
```

- `db` sería el objeto `Conexion`, el mismo que usarías para conectarte a la BD
- `SELECT 1 ...` es una de las formas para simplificar una consulta cuando sólo se quiere evaluar si hay registros. Hay otras como `SELECT COUNT(*)`, seleccionar el id, etc... Según el manejador de BD y la estructura de las tablas puede haber una ligera variación en cuanto al rendimiento según uses una u otra.

Answer (score 3):

**Yo lo realizo de la siguiente forma espero te ayude es simple**

```
public  boolean dbexisteRegistro(Connection Conn, String id_a_buscar){
         Statement oSt = null;
         ResultSet oRs = null;
         String sSQL= " ";
         boolean dbexisteRegistro= false; 

         try{
             Conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
             sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Nombre_de_tu_tabla WHERE ID_A_BUSCAR='" + id_a_buscar + "'";


             oSt = Conn.createStatement();
             oRs = oSt.executeQuery(sSQL);

             if(oRs.next()){
                if(oRs.getRow() > 0){
                    dbexisteRegistro= true;
                }
             }

             if (oSt != null) {oSt.close();oSt = null;}
             if (oRs != null) {oRs.close();oRs = null;}
         }catch(SQLException err){

             oSt = null;
             oRs = null;
             sSQL=null;
         }catch(Exception err){

             oSt = null;
             oRs = null;
             sSQL=null;  
         }finally{
             oSt = null;
             oRs = null;
             sSQL=null;
         }
         return dbexisteRegistro;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Connection con = new Conexion().getConexion();
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo_id = 1");
        if(rs.last()){
            //Existe
        }
        else{
            //No Existe
        }
```

Comment: Por favor Alexis, añade la explicacion , no solo el codigo. MIra [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Esta forma de hacerlo es muy similar a la de @A. Cedano, sin embargo, en el método del compañero hay que usar un `throws SQLException`y por ende definir la excepción a la hora de llamar al método, cosa que con el siguiente método ya no se debe hacer.

**Declaración del método**

```js
public boolean verificarPaciente(int idPaciente) {        
        boolean res = false;       
        String verificar = "SELECT k_numdocumento FROM paciente WHERE k_numdocumento = "+idPaciente;
        try{
            ps = cn.conectar().prepareStatement(verificar);            
            rs = ps.executeQuery();        
            if(rs.next())
                res = true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.err.print("Ha ocurrido un error: "+ e.getMessage());
        } 
        finally{
            ps = null;
            cn.close();
        }        
        return res;
    }
```

**Llamar el método**

```js
if(sc.verificarPaciente(Integer.parseInt(Id.getText())))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," El usuario ya existe");
else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," El usuario no existe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice de la siguiente forma y funciona a la perfección, espero les funcione el pequeño aporte:

```java
Conexion cnx = new Conexion();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet res;
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(id_mensaje) FROM mensajes WHERE id_mensaje= "+id_mensaje+"";
ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
res = ps.executeQuery();
if (res.next()) {
    String count  = res.getString("count(id_mensaje)");
    System.out.println(count);
}
```